# PHP date format not displaying correctly

Tags: php, date-format

Trying to get the date to display desired format of m-d-Y but its still displaying Y-m-d

3 lines of code in question

```
'post_modified_gmt' => date_format(date("m-d-Y H:i:s")),
$gmttt = date_format(date('m-d-Y H:i:s'));
$this->submittedat =  get_date_from_gmt( date_format(date("m-d-Y H:i:s")));
```

Comment: you are missing `date_format` parameters https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php

Comment: Can you just print the value of date ?  `var_dump($gmttt);`, also put the value in question.

Answer (score 0):

Just using this it can display current date format of m-d-Y  :

```
echo date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
```

Comment: in php test that works but im something else seems to be interfering with the format displaying correctly

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php.

Following is the snippet in above php manual website,

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

what you can do is,

```
$dt = date_create('now');
$date = date_format($dt, 'm-d-Y H:i:s');
var_dump($date);
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>'
`'post_modified_gmt' => $date,`

Comment: please post your full code in question or comment out that line where error is showing

Comment: its 936 lines long

Comment: ok few lines like 10 lines above from the line where error is showing.

Comment: `function getFormFields()
  {
    $this->submittedby = htmlentities($this->formatSQLsafe($_POST["submittedby"]));
    $this->mapname = htmlentities($this->formatSQLsafe($_POST["mapname"]));
    $this->mapdesc = htmlentities($this->formatSQLsafe($_POST["mapdescription"]));
    $this->mapurl = htmlentities($this->formatSQLsafe($_POST["mapurl"]));
    $dt = date_create('now');
    $date = date_format($dt, 'm-d-Y H:i');
    $gmttt = $date;
    $this->submittedat =  get_date_from_gmt($date);
    $this->intendedaudience = $_POST["intendedaudience"];
  }`

Comment: looks fine, you removed the line where error was showing, you are good to go, try now.

Comment: date_format($dt, 'm-d-Y H:i') <----- should be date_format($dt, 'm-d-Y H:i:s')

Comment: didnt want to display `s` so I removed it, also I think there is a chasing issue or something as the date format hasnt changed

Comment: try `var_dump($date);` to see the format.